# Getting the total number of records in a database table

Tags: c#, mysql

I am currently developing a windows form project, in this project I have got a database table. My main question is how can i get the total of records in a specific column? and display the number of total record on label?

I have done some research about this and I have  come across a method called "DataRow" if this is right, how can I go about in implementing this in my project?

Comment: this is a very vague question, you want us to do your work?

Comment: No, I just needed an idea to be honest ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about your research though it wasn't enough :) but `Count` is a function which you want to use.

```
SELECT COUNT(columnName) as TotalRecords from TableName
```

P:S. whenever do research always try to use google :)

Comment: Thank you, I think that's all i needed sir! :)